# Show email on webView?

Tags: android, email, webview, mime-types

I m fetching whole E-mail Content except attachments and inserting it in a db as String. But when I fetch it from db and load it on webView with following code it doesnt open mail properly.

`mailView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, body, "text/plain", "UTF-8", null);`

When I look at the types of content of mail Part it gives me many kind of `mime types` such as  "text/html" , "text/plain" , "multipart/alternative" and many more as per the content of email. I dont know how to load mail consisting multiple `mime` types.Here I am attaching some images of a demo project showing this mail functionality please go through  them:[image: Demo_mail image showing plain and html text.]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by making sure your database is storing the data in the proper encoding.  It could be losing UTF-8 data.

Comment: This is more of a comment than a solution.  Perhaps you can expound a little?

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem and solved it as below steps :

1. extract the body of the email as text/plain or text/html, if as
   text/plain, you need to escape the content so it can be displayed in
   the webview correctly.
2. use the below way to call the loadDataWithBaseURL() :
   mMessageContentView.loadDataWithBaseURL("email://", html,
   "text/html", "utf-8", null);

Good Luck.

Comment: This did work for me(I chose the 2nd option). Thank you